# Calculate the time difference between same or different TimeZone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript and JQuery. I am trying to calculate time difference between current time on my machine and a given time in below format.

```
December 12 2015 14:00:00 UTC-0800
```

The above format contains TimeZone and the problem is, it can be any timezone in the above time format.

is there any predefined function to calculate the time difference easily ?

Comment: no. the js date/time object is (pathetically) limited. you'll have to roll your own, or use an external library, e.g. moment.js

Comment: Gods, I remember having to do this once.  It was a huge pain, every conceivable problem reared its ugly head.  I don't have access to that code any more, though.  Even to this day, I still don't know why we took the client's timestamp for one thing and the server's for something else, and expected the difference between them to be meaningful.

Comment: From MDN: the Date object "if used to create a local date object, will reflect the local equivalent of the time"  You should be able to find the difference that way. Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/c0d213bg/  Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: You've completely changed your question. You should have opened a new question. Now the answers and comments, which were related to the original question, are completely unrelated.

Comment: I've rolled back to your original question. Please do not changed your question again. If you do want to ask another question, create a new one.

Comment: @Helper Please stop editing your question. When you change the question, you invalidate the answers. You have already answered this question and even marked an answer as accepted. To ask a new question, use the [**Ask Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button instead of changing this question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) is an option, you can use that to parse the time string, and retrieve a timezone-corrected `Date` object. You can them compare that to the local time:

```js
var datestr = "December 12 2015 14:00:00 UTC-0800";

// get target time as a JavaScript Date
var m = moment(datestr, "MMMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [UTC]Z").toDate();

var now = new Date();   // current time as a Date 

// get the difference (in milliseconds) between the two
var diffInMs = m - now;

// use moment.duration to display it in a readable form
var dur = moment.duration(diffInMs, "ms");
console.log( dur.humanize() );

var hours = Math.floor( diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60) );
var seconds = Math.floor( diffInMs / 1000 );

console.log( "hours: " + hours );
console.log( "seconds: " + seconds );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @bags Yes, but not in this exact format. The string would need to be transformed into one of the supported formats, otherwise the results would be unpredictable. With moment, all you need is a format spec. There are certainly other ways to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The date string format above seems to work though, no? (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0d213bg/). What am I missing?